# Strange Chrome Extension behavior

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a simple chrome extension, which at the moment just renders a popup.html page.  However, sometimes when I click my extension, it isn't rendered fully - a small section will appear, however the rest of the background will be transparent.  Example:

Here is the extension, with Bootstrap, working normally:

[image]

However, sometimes when it is loaded, the popup works but this is shown:

[image]

As you can see, the box appears, there is a small section in the top left corner and the rest of the box is transparent.  The only way to get rid of this is to relaunch the extension.

The only CSS I have is the standard Bootstrap css, and my custom:

```
body {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a bug, can you create a minimal extension to demonstrate the issue, and create a report at http://crbug.com/new?

Comment: Okay will do.  Searched the other issues and can't find anything similar.  Maybe it's just with Bootstrap, but either way I'll do it.